# Running the dotnet command to make a compiler on Macbook

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction

I am watching this video [Episode 18: Emitting IL Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9b8-okd-ZkU&list=PLRAdsfhKI4OWNOSfS7EUu5GRAVmze1t2y&index=19), and at 39:14 minutes, he opens two terminals. In one, he runs the command `dotnet run -- ..\..\samples\hello`, which generates a hello.exe. After that, he opens another terminal and uses `ilspycmd` to inspect the compilation of the file.

I am using a MacBook M1, and I am aware of the limitations of the .exe extension on Unix systems. However, I tested it with a C# code, opening the .exe, and it worked, displaying the message in the terminal.

My issue is that when I run the command `dotnet run -- ../samples/hello`, it shows the following two messages:

```
outputPath=../samples/hello.exe
Erro: file '../samples/hello' does not exist.
```

However, the directory samples/hello does exist, and it contains a file named hello.ms with the message print("Hello World!").

I'm not sure if this could be related to running a different tasks.json depending on the operating system, but below is the tasks.json that I created and my [Github repository](https://github.com/vagnerwentz/cthulhu-compiler).

### tasks.json

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "build",
      "command": "dotnet",
      "type": "process",
      "args": ["build", "${workspaceFolder}/CompilerOOPWentz.sln"],
      "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    },
    {
      "label": "mc",
      "command": "dotnet",
      "type": "shell",
      "args": [
        "run",
        "--project",
        "${workspaceFolder}/Runner/Runner.csproj",
        "--",
        "${fileDirname}"
      ],
      "presentation": {
        "echo": true,
        "reveal": "always",
        "focus": true,
        "panel": "shared",
        "showReuseMessage": false,
        "clear": true
      },
      "problemMatcher": {
        "fileLocation": "absolute",
        "pattern": [
          {
            "regexp": "^(.*)\\((\\d,\\d\\,\\d\\,\\d\\))\\: (.*)$",
            "file": 1,
            "location": 2,
            "message": 3
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

### What I tried

- I tried to run the dotnet command by different styles
- Installed the ilspycmd on Macbook and it worked

I expect to resolve the problem that it's saying the path does not exist and create `.exe` on Macbook.

### Notice

I have a validation about if path exists using `File.Exists` you can see below.

```cs
foreach (var path in sourcePaths)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"path={path}");
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine($"1 - Erro: arquivo '{path}' não existe.");
        hasErrors = true;
        continue;
    }
    var syntaxTree = SyntaxTree.Load(path);
    syntaxTrees.Add(syntaxTree);
}
```

The log is `path=../samples/hello` and `1 - Erro: arquivo '../samples/hello' não existe.`, but I have the structure with `samples/hello` as you can see in the image below.
[image: Image about folder structure]